# AEM adaptive forms, In checkbox components accessibility tab, custom tags are not working

Tags: forms, accessibility, aem

AEM adaptive forms, In checkbox components accessibility tab, custom tags are not working .

In aem adaptive forms.
When i try to add the accessibility custom tags for checkbox component, I see it is not adding aria label to the field.
But it is working fine in other radio button component.

Please help me with the solution

Comment: It would be really useful if you could share a fiddle with your code in. Most people will not have used AEM forms, but we can often spot issues on code once we can see what you have tried. Can you share a fiddle that way we can (hopefully) help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.